# Can't get search data from ViewModel to Activity Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel

I'm trying to get my data from my ViewModel to my MainActivity.

I know that what I'm doing in my `MainActivity` is very wrong, but I can't seem to configure it in a way that will get the data into the MainActivity.  It's just a simple string.

**ViewModel**

```
class MovieSearchViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var searchTerm = ""

    fun getSearchTerm(query: String) {
        searchTerm = query
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
open class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val viewModel: MovieSearchViewModel by viewModels()
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

         var searchTerm = viewModel.searchTerm
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the data for the string? `getSearchTerm` should be renamed to `setSearchTerm` as it is a setter function. And call it using the data required to set the data.

Comment: The data comes from a search bar in a fragment, is then passed to the ViewModel and needs to go to the MainActivity.

Comment: You are getting the data on Activity `onCreate`. So the data might not be set at that point. You have to use LiveData to get updated data from ViewModel

Comment: Yeah, I've been playing around with that. I'll keep working on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**View Model**

you can use LiveData to always get the latest data in Activity

```
var searchTerm = MutableLiveData("")
fun setSearchTerm(query: String){
    searchTerm.value = query
}
```

**MainActivity**

in observe it will always run every time there is a data change

```
viewModel.searchTerm.observe(this){
     Log.e("tag", it)
}
```

or

if you want get the data manually without observe you can do like this

```
var data = viewModel.searchTerm.value
```

Comment: What would go into the "update data" in the `MainActivity`?  If I just wanted to do something simple like print the string to the console, what would that look like?

Comment: yeah you can do it, example 
viewModel.searchTerm.observe(this){
       Log.e("tag", it)
}